# Reading text from file in GUI

Tags: java

I am stuck at reading text from a file into text area.I don't know why but my file reader never opens the file even if it exists.I am getting file name from a text field and using a button listener to trigger this event.So any help will be appreciated. I've given my code to below.

```
try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tf1.getText()));

    while((read = br.readLine())!=null){
       store = store + read;
    }
    ta.setText(store);
    fr.close();
    br.close();
    jf2.dispose();
}
catch(Exception exp){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Not Found.");
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on _my file reader never opens the file even if it exists_?  I would also change that catch block to be specific for `FileNotFoundException` and still throw generic exceptions so you know what is happening

Comment: It is not a good idea to ignore the content of `exp`, because this contains information about your problem. You can print its content by using `exp.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Take a look at [TextComponent#read(Reader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object)), which will allow you to read a file into the text component (or JTextArea in this case)

Comment: You should think about using the [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) instead of a simple text field.

Comment: Well it gave me FileNotFound Exception when i printed.

Comment: Ok i've just done the reverse of above problem i.e i've saved the text from text area into another file which user gave me in the text field and it worked perfectly.That's odd.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(tf1.getText())));
```

It is important to note that you need to have a "File" that encapsulates your text to open the actual file. Otherwise, the JVM does not know in which part of the harddisk to search for.

Good luck.

Comment: FileReader takes a String parameter as a file reference [FileReader(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader(java.lang.String))

Comment: Yup it's right [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader-java.lang.String-) in the docs...

Comment: Yes, its either that or a file, however though, creating the filereader with the overloaded constructor that accepts the file will give a greater indication of where the error is.

Comment: Simply print the stacktrace. The thing is though, that the code does not sanitize the text-input to make sure that it is a "parsable" file-path. For instance a very common mistake is to conflate "\" and "//". So input sanitzation is the way to go before you proceed with any of this.

Comment: @SalmanJaved well then there must be something wrong with your code other than the snippet provided.

To help you better, please show me your exact filepath to your actual file on your PC. Also, please print out the "tf1.getText()" just to make sure that you are entering parsable input

Comment: i've already printed and it gets correct file name.i've put the file to be read in the same folder that contains this code file.